# How to access user-defined capabilities in yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Given a user-defined capabilities in some of the self-hosted agent, for example:

Name: InHouse.BuildTools

Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Build Tools\builder.exe

In the yaml pipeline, how to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Build Tools\builder.exe' by using the variable of $(InHouse.BuildTools) without hard-coding the actual path?

Answer (score -1):

Since Azure agent capabilities get set as environment variables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities), you could use a powershell script task to write it as an output variable for use later in your pipeline. Something like this should work:

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: |
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildToolsPath;isOutput=true]${env:INHOUSE_BUILDTOOLS}"
    name: getBuildToolsPath
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    buildToolsPathFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['getBuildToolsPath.buildToolsPath'] ]  
  steps:
    #use variable as $(buildToolsPathFromJobA) in these steps
```

(code adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs)

Comment: Reading the article you linked, environment variables on the agent machine get written to capabilities, not the other way around.